# Is it possible to ensure that requests come from a specific domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, url, controller, request

I'm making a Rails polling site, which should have results that are very accurate. Users vote using POST links. I've taken pains to make sure users only vote once, and know exactly what they're voting for.

But it occurred to me that third parties with an interest in the results could put up POST links on their own websites, that point to my voting paths. They could skew my results this way, for example by adding a misleading description.

Is there any way of making sure that the requests can only come from my domain? So a link coming from a different domain wouldn't run any of the code in my controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various things that you'll need to check.  First is `request.referer`, which will tell you the page that referred the link to your site.  If it's not your site, you should reject it.

```
if URI(request.referer).host != my_host
    raise ArgumentError.new, "Invalid request from external domain"
end
```

However, this only protects you from web clients (browsers) that accurately populate the HTTP `referer` header.  And that's assuming that it came from a web page at all.  For instance, someone could send a link by email, and an email client is unlikely to provide a referer at all.

In the case of no referer, you can check for that, as well:

```
if request.referer.blank?
  raise ArgumentError.new, "Invalid request from unknown domain"
elsif URI(request.referer).host != my_host
  raise ArgumentError.new, "Invalid request from external domain"
end
```

It's also very easy with simple scripting to spoof the HTTP 'referer', so even if you do get a valid domain, you'll need other checks to ensure that it's a legitimate POST.  Script kiddies do this sort of thing all the time, and with a dozen or so lines of Ruby, python, perl, curl, or even VBA, you can simulate interaction by a "real user".

You may want to use something like a request/response key mechanism.  In this approach, the link served from your site includes a unique key (that you track) for each visit to the page, and that only someone with that key can vote.

How you identify voters is important, as well.  Passive identification techniques are good for non-critical activities, such as serving advertisements or making recommendations.  However, this approach regularly fails a measurable percentage of the time when used across the general population.  When you also consider the fact that people actually *want* to corrupt voting activities, it's very easy to suddenly become a target for everyone with a good concept to "beat the system" and some spare time on their hands.

Build in as much security as possible early on, because you'll need far more than you expect.  During the 2012 Presidential Election, I was asked to pre-test 41 online voting sites, and was able to break 39 of them within the first 24 hours (6 of them within 1 hour).  Be overly cautious.  Know how attackers can get in, not just using "normal" mechanisms.  Don't publish information about which technologies you're using, even in the code.  Seeing "Rails-isms" anywhere in the HTML or Javascript code (or even the URL pathnames) will immediately give the attacker an enormous edge in defeating your safety mechanisms.  Use obscurity to your advantage, and use security everywhere that you can.

NOTE: Checking the `request.referer` is like putting a padlock on a bank vault: it'll keep out those that are easily dissuaded, but won't even slow down the determined individual.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! Do you know of a source I can use to learn more about the request/response key mechanism you mentioned?

Comment: As @DaSourcerer pointed out, Rails includes CSRF protection, which will help prevent one website from posting to another.  (Please upvote his answer for that great information!).  That will keep the casual cross-site hackers out, however, that won't help much against attackers that are capable of writing scripts to drive your site.  I'll see if I can dig up some good references.  In the meantime, you might look at what the `mechanize` gem can do - it's representative of a serious website hacking tool that people might actually use to cast votes automatically.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to prevent here is basically [cross-site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). As Michael correctly pointed out, checking the `Referer` header will buy you nothing.

A popular counter-measure is to give each user an individual one-time token that is sent with each form and stored in the user's session. If, on submit, the submitted value and the stored value do not match, the request is disgarded. Luckily for you, RoR seems to [ship such a feature](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf). Looks like a one-liner indeed.